# Importing and filtering RSS feeds into nodes

Tags: nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

I'm looking for the best way to import a feed, say BBC News, and filter through all the content so only articles containing a keyword are stored in the database. I'd like each item to be shown as a node of a specific content type and for it to be updated every given time interval. Is there a straightforward way to do this? I don't have much experience in PHP at all, so please be specific.

Answer (score 3):

The friendliest UI driven way to do this is probably with the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds). Make your content type(s) using Drupal Fields and use Feeds to ingest the content via Cron or job_scheduler module. You might still need to code a simple module to do some things ... but it would require little coding I think.

The less friendly way would be the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) (has a status-indicator UI, but no helpful UI for creating/moving fields). You'd end up coding alot of php to rip through XML and create X nodes in some content type. But, you'd still get a way to import/update/rollback items from RSS. They do have XML "News" examples I think in the Migrate modules example folder in the project.

I'd go with Feeds if you're new to this and stumble your way through that ... I haven't used it. I can only recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your import by keyword with the [feeds_tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module. Also in order to import RSS, you can configure an importer with the [xpathparser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) module in order to select what content / fields to import.